# Iterating through an object of objects in a foreach loop in php

Tags: php, oop, foreach

I have a function that is being passed an object that contains other objects that have permission ids in them.  I need those permission ids in a foreach loop.  Most of my tries give me an array to string conversion or a call to a non-object error.

A formatted var_dump of $permission looks like this...

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[9]
          public 'permission_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[11]
          public 'permission_id' => string '2' (length=1)

//My function starts off like this...

function checkPermission($permission) {
  $db = DB::getInstance();
  global $user;

  foreach($permission as $key=>$value){
```

I need to figure out how to setup that foreach loop where every round of the loop passes in that permission_id from the var_dump above.

Comment: you have array[array][object], basically, `$permission[0][0]->permission_id`

Comment: what do I put in place of the [0][0] to make it loop through properly?

Comment: well, if you don't ever expect more items at the top level array, then `foreach($permissions[0] as $subperm) { $subperm->permission_id }`

Comment: That worked! I don't think I would have guessed that in a million years.  Thank you!